# How to use lamda to get not equals value on a scope in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a scope thats not currently working.
 `scope :not_voided, lambda { where('workflow_state != ?', "voided") }`

I want to get all orders that don't have a workflow_state of "voided"

I'm really struggling with it and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is 'not working' about this? It's valid syntax for rails 5. Are you seeing unexpected results?

Comment: I thought the same but it returns orders with all types of states "voided" included

Comment: Oh mate its because I called the scope in wrong controller I was testing tables/orders not orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code actually works as expected.